# XAMPP 5.5.28 doesn't work on OS X 10.11

Tags: apache, xampp, osx-elcapitan

My iMac' OS was upgraded last night, to OS X El Capitan(version 10.11).

I use XAMPP 5.5.28. MySQL and ProFTPD are working, but the Apache Web Server doesn't work after the upgrade.

Even though the application log says..

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
```

Then tried to start it on Terminal

```
$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd 
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

I checked whether any other app uses the same port by

```
$ netstat -anp tcp | grep :80
```

And nothing uses it.

Anyway, to avoid the error, I changed the port 80 to 8888 by

```
$ vi /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf
```

Then tried to start the web server on Terminal again, and it worked.

Now wondering

1. **Which process uses port `80`?**
2. **How can I start the web server via Application Manager of XAMPP?**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem
And I thought this is a dead end for El Capitan
BUT i got it working now:
The problem was apache was already running, no idea how.
So just go to terminal and type (Login as root user)

```
    sudo su -
    cd /etc/apache2/
    apachectl stop
    exit
```

Then go to XAMPP and try to start apache from there.
If this doesn't work, restart your system, then go to terminal:

```
    sudo su -
    cd /etc/apache2/
    apachectl start
    apachectl stop
    exit
```

Then go to XAMPP and try to start apache from there.

Comment: you rock! It exactly worked!

Comment: Great, It worked for me. I have installed symfony3 and then created the virtual host for it on my mac with XAMP. Every thing was working fine and after restarting the MAC this error was appearing. After searching lot on the forums I came to this post and it solved the issue.